Can we set bid floor in max applovin, or pass values, equivalent to key pair value? and max will take that value as bid floor?
Can we set bid floor in max 'applovin', or pass values, equivalent to key pair value? and max will take that value as bid floor? i know bid f via country is available, but i do not want to put the bid floor country specific, i want to pass values to max and it should be able to set the bid floor. Please help.
Thank you
I have read the documentations and there is no such mention. Maybe i overlooked something, maybe there is a work around.
I have tried to read the forum but unable to find anything on it. So let me know if it is possible?
